# In Objective-C MRR, if foo is a retain property, then self.foo = [[Foo alloc] init] will need to be released immediately?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am using ARC but reading the MRR part of Objective-C, and it seems like if a property of `ViewController` is (for non-ARC):

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) Foo *foo;
```

then the `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController` will need to do a `release` right after `alloc` and `init`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    [self.foo release];

}
```

Otherwise, the `retain` will increment the reference count of the Foo object once when it is assigned to `_foo` (the instance variable), and `alloc` also increment the reference count once, so it is claiming ownership twice, and therefore, there needs to be a `release` right after the `alloc` and `init`?

I just feel it is a bit weird looking because an `alloc` is immediately followed by a `release` this way.

(If we do is a `self.foo = [Foo fooByString: @"hello"]`, then one ownership is claimed by the autorelease pool, and one claimed by ViewController, and at the end of the event loop, the autorelease pool drains, and unclaim one ownership, and therefore the Foo object is correctly owned once only.  (but if Foo doesn't have such methods and only have `alloc` and `init`, then the immediate `release` is needed.))

Comment: Note that you should never, ever call `[self.foo release]`. You do not own the thing returned by `[self foo]` ("foo" does not begin with "alloc", "copy", or "new"), so you must not release it. Do not assume implementation details of `-foo`. See @Matt Wilding's answer for the correct approaches. Note that there is almost no reason to use manual memory management anymore. All projects should move to ARC as quickly as practical.

Comment: interesting... or what if Foo is my own class and the interface clearly states that they just set or get the instance variable? (my coding practice is that I only do that and nothing else).

Comment: There are explicit naming rules for object ownership in ObjC. They are not a matter of personal style. You do not own the object that is returned by `[self foo]` no matter what you know about the internal implementation details. If you run the static analyzer on the above code, you will note that it complains (as it should). If you combine ARC and non-ARC code, then naming violations will lead to memory errors.

Comment: Note that this is a major difference between ObjC and C++. C++ has a strict compiler and loose conventions (everyone tends to make up their own). ObjC has a loose compiler (it will accept all kinds of craziness) and strict conventions.

Comment: So use one of the two approaches by Matt?  The idea that the ViewController doesn't own the object returned by `[self foo]` or `self.foo` is ... somewhat anti-intuitive?  Because, doesn't the line `@property (retain) Foo *foo` means, when `self.foo = bar` is run, claim the ownership of `bar`?

Comment: @JeremyL, as Rob said, there are rigid naming conventions indicating what you do and do not own. If a method name contains any of [new, alloc, retain, copy], you own the returned object. Otherwise you do not. You also never release what you do not own. Practically speaking, in your case you'll be fine, but it's better to _always_ follow those conventions. Consider the case where the getter is manually implemented to return an autoreleased copy of the original. If you then `release` that object, you'll crash with a double release because you assumed `[self foo]` was returning the backing ivar.

Comment: The word "own" has a somewhat different meaning in ObjC as well (and a somewhat confusing meaning IMO). ObjC has multiple ownership. No object really "owns" another; it "owns a retain" on another. You may want to drop the word "own" from this and think of it as "you only release variables you retained; you retain by calling methods starting with alloc, copy, mutableCopy, or new, or by calling retain."

Comment: The other key to understand is that properties are just promises to implement methods. There is very little different between having a readonly property "foo" and just having a method called "foo." Even things like "copy" and "strong" are just semantic promises (and sometimes just semantic hints). They're not implementation promises. In particular, there is no general promise that a strong getter will return the same object passed to the setter. There is no promise that a copy setter will actually make a real copy. It's just a promise that the result will be equivalent.

Comment: I see what you mean... you mean the `foo` in `self.foo` or `[self foo]` is treated as a method whose name is not `alloc`, `new`, etc, so that why we can't release... but if it is `_foo = [[Foo alloc] init]]; [_foo release];` then it is fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially correct, though there are a few ways that it was typically done to make it look less awkward:

```
Foo* someFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];
self.foo = someFoo;
[someFoo release];
```

Or more succinctly:

```
self.foo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: are you sure `autorelease` will do it?  It is like, let the autorelease pool claim yet another ownership, which will be decremented at the end of main event loop... so the reference count will still be 2.

Comment: The autorelease balances the init. Don't worry about when it does so, just know that it does. That leaves the only outstanding conceptual retain count as the one from the property assignment.

Comment: this kind of shattered my understanding of autorelease... I thought it is for a factory method, so that after the `alloc` and `init`, it has no way to unclaim ownership later, and cannot unclaim ownership now (needs to return to the caller), so, just add it to the autorelease pool... oh... I get it, it just add to the autorelease pool, but does not increment the reference count...  so why not just do inside of `viewDidLoad` the following: `self.foo = [[[Foo alloc] init] release]`?

Comment: Because the `release` will be called before the assignment, which will likely result in the deallocation of newly created object before it is assigned to the property. You need to ensure that the balancing of the `init` happens _after_ assignment, either by explicitly releasing immediately after, or by autoreleasing before.

Comment: MRR is quite complicated... it seems like you need to understand every single detail of it... not the running of the program, but balance of reference count so that it is exactly 0 when not needed

Comment: MRR is simple at heart, but it does take experience to understand all of its implications. Thus, ARC.

Comment: Consistent naming and use of accessors eliminates almost all of the complexity of manual reference counting. But ARC does it with less code and faster. Thus, ARC. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your viewController's constructor/init, what you need to do is:

```
_foo=[[Foo alloc] init];
```

To avoid the unnecessary release call, since the alloc/init creates a non-autorelease instance of foo. Also, it will remove the need to have the autorelease pool to work on an object that we have complete control of its initialization. You know you want foo to be owner by your viewController. It's unnecessary to claim ownership twice just to have the retain count decreased at the return of the runloop.

Comment: If `_foo` had a previous value, this leaks it. You should avoid this style because it is very prone to this kind of bug. Use the accessor except in `init` and `dealloc`.

Comment: Good point. I use this usually on my custom class's init method. I should have been more specific about this pattern.

Comment: Yes, in `init` this is correct. The OP's example was in `viewDidLoad`, and I've seen a lot of people leak values exactly there (because they assume `viewDidLoad` will only be called once).